# Which version of Ubuntu should I use?

Tags: system-installation

I just bought a laptop (Sony Vaio fit 15), is a touch laptop with 8GB RAM, i7 processor (2.00 - 3.10ghz). I have installed Windows 8.1, and I would like to know which exact version of Ubuntu should I buy or download to get the maximum performance.

I'm not an Ubuntu user and I do not know much about Ubuntu, but I want to get started in this.

Comment: If it runs Win8 it will run any Ubuntu version.

Comment: What I want to know is, What exact version of ubuntu you recommend? taking clear that my computer is touch. And I want to know which is better, buy the cd or download?

Comment: if you buy the CD or download an iso is just the same, but downloading the ISO *should* be faster...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would like to be using the latest features in Ubuntu and start playing with it and your not worried about 5 year extended support because you will be upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 if you start using it soon so my recommendation is to install the latest stable Ubuntu version:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?release=latest&bits=64&distro=desktop&status=zeroc

If you like a nice interface and very simple to use:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/GetUbuntuGNOME

There are more if you wish to look arround but my favourite is Gnome Ubuntu.

PS: Remember to use the 64 bit version of Ubuntu to use all your RAM and get the best performance.
I think Gnome Ubuntu is much better for touch screens :)

Comment: Unity is fine for touchscreens as well, and the 32 bit versions can handle up to 64GB of RAM but it slows down above 4GB (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/32bit_and_64bit#Memory). Either one works.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you use the LTS version.  The support will be better.

http://www.howtogeek.com/162768/should-you-use-ubuntu-lts-or-upgrade-to-the-latest-release/

Comment: What about https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases?

Comment: What I want to know is, What exact version of ubuntu you recommend? taking clear that my computer is touch. And I want to know which is better, buy the cd or download?

Comment: The version I would recommend would be 13.10, the direct link is above and buying the CD will be exactly the same as the download but you will be contributing Ubuntu. Hope you are answered :)